# Data is not inserting to the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to asp .net MVC 4.

I have one text box and the text box value I am  fetching from  one table.But while clicking on submit button this value I want to insert into different table , which is not inserting and showing error.It is taking value as null.

**coding**

**View**

```
@Html.TextBox("empname", (string)ViewBag.empname, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

**controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Facilities()
{
    mstEmpDetail emp = new mstEmpDetail();
    emp = db.mstEmpDetails.Single(x => x.intEmpId == 10001);
    ViewBag.empname = emp.txtEmpFirstName;

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Facilities(TrnBusinessCardDetail bc)
{
    var empname1 = ViewBag.empname;
    bc.txtfirstName = empname1;
    db.TrnBusinessCardDetails.Add(bc);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Facilities");
}
```

While I was working with normal text box it was inserting properly,but when I have retrieve
fro DB then i am getting this problem ?
How to solve this problem ?

Comment: **What** database are you using? Can you show us the connection string you're using to connect to your database??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @dotnetom, ViewBag is a one way street. MVC is stateless so a POST request is not a "Round Trip" from previous get request. Thus your ViewBag can not hold its state.

MVC can determine (and construct) your action parameters from Form Parameters. In your case you have added a textbox with name "empname". So you should get this value as parameter in your POST request.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Facilities(TrnBusinessCardDetail bc, string empname)
    {
        bc.txtfirstName = empname;
        db.TrnBusinessCardDetails.Add(bc);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Facilities");
    }
```

This would be simplest of solution given your problem. More appropriate would be binding your textbox directly with you model property. This way you will not have to worry about retrieving and assigning property value to model in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Viewbag is a one way street - you can use it to pass information to the view, but you cannot use it to get the information from the view. The statement `ViewBag.empname` in your POST method has a value of null in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when you are using  `var empname1 = ViewBag.empname;` in post controller because `ViewBag.empname` lost its value at that time.